# How to fill-in EditText field in Android tests

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-testing

Does anybody have any experience with creating tests for an android project? I started setting up my testing project and noticed that there is not much documentation at all. I am trying to setup a test to test a username and password field. I have it working without filling in the inputs username or password. But now when I try to set those up I keep getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` but I don't see why or how. Here is a sample of code that I am working on.

```
public class GasTrackerTab1Test extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<GasTrackerTab1> {  
    private Activity mActivity; // MyActivity is the class name of the app under test
    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;
    private Button loginButton;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public GasTrackerTab1Test() {
        super("com.wallproductions.gas.tracker", GasTrackerTab1.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        /*
         * Call the super constructor (required by JUnit)
         */

        super.setUp();

        /*
         * prepare to send key events to the app under test by turning off touch mode.
         * Must be done before the first call to getActivity()
         */
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

        /*
         * Start the app under test by starting its main activity. The test runner already knows
         * which activity this is from the call to the super constructor, as mentioned
         * previously. The tests can now use instrumentation to directly access the main
         * activity through mActivity.
         */
        mActivity = getActivity();

        username = (EditText)mActivity.findViewById(com.wallproductions.gas.tracker.R.id.login_user_name);
        password = (EditText)mActivity.findViewById(com.wallproductions.gas.tracker.R.id.login_password);
        loginButton = (Button)mActivity.findViewById(com.wallproductions.gas.tracker.R.id.mainloginbtn);

    } // end of setUp() method definition

    /*
     * Tests the initial values of key objects in the app under test, to ensure the initial
     * conditions make sense. If one of these is not initialized correctly, then subsequent
     * tests are suspect and should be ignored.
     */

    public void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull(username);
        assertNotNull(password);
    }

    public void testInvalidUserNamePassword() {
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    username.setFocus();
                    username.setText("tester");
                    password.setFocus();
                    password.setText("test1234");
                    loginButton.performClick();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The question is there any good documentation to look at to figure this out? Also how do you fill in a EditText box with some text and then verify through an alert that the correct response is given.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:
`onView(withId(R.id.text_edit_id)).perform(typeText(someString));`

Comment: Hey, while this may solve the problem, it is encouraged to also explain what went wrong and how your code snippet fixes it

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found my answer at

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-tools-tradefederation/com/android/tradefed/uitestapp/EditBoxActivityTest.java.htm

Basically I needed to add in @UiThreadTest above my method and then using setText works. Not using the Runable class.

```
public class GasTrackerTab1Test extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<GasTrackerTab1> {  
    private Activity mActivity; // MyActivity is the class name of the app under test
    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;
    private Button loginButton;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public GasTrackerTab1Test() {
        super("com.wallproductions.gas.tracker", GasTrackerTab1.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        /*
         * Call the super constructor (required by JUnit)
         */

        super.setUp();

        /*
         * prepare to send key events to the app under test by turning off touch mode.
         * Must be done before the first call to getActivity()
         */
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

        /*
         * Start the app under test by starting its main activity. The test runner already knows
         * which activity this is from the call to the super constructor, as mentioned
         * previously. The tests can now use instrumentation to directly access the main
         * activity through mActivity.
         */
        mActivity = getActivity();

        username = (EditText)mActivity.findViewById(com.wallproductions.gas.tracker.R.id.login_user_name);
        password = (EditText)mActivity.findViewById(com.wallproductions.gas.tracker.R.id.login_password);
        loginButton = (Button)mActivity.findViewById(com.wallproductions.gas.tracker.R.id.mainloginbtn);

    } // end of setUp() method definition

    /*
     * Tests the initial values of key objects in the app under test, to ensure the initial
     * conditions make sense. If one of these is not initialized correctly, then subsequent
     * tests are suspect and should be ignored.
     */

    public void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull(username);
        assertNotNull(password);
    }

    /**
     * Test that the edit box on {@link EditBoxActivity} can focused.
     */
    @UiThreadTest
    public void testUsernameTextFocus() {
        assertNotNull(username);
        assertTrue(username.requestFocus());
        assertTrue(username.hasFocus());
    }

    @UiThreadTest
    public void testPasswordTextFocus() {
        assertNotNull(password);
        assertTrue(password.requestFocus());
        assertTrue(password.hasFocus());
    }

    @UiThreadTest
    public void testInvalidUserNamePassword() {     
        username.requestFocus();
        username.setText("testing");
        password.requestFocus();
        password.setText("whatever");
        loginButton.callOnClick();
    }
}
```